# JavaFx How to get CSS property of element

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine

I want to use JavaFX to extract some features of website`s elements.

For example, I would like to know background color, height and width of specific div element.

JavaFX can render html pages with CSS and JS, but how can I access this information? Is there some api to access and traverse tree of rendered html alongside with CSS?

Comment: You can read css using javascript and you can get the results in webengine, check the docs for javascript.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and I am no JavaFX CSS maven, you cannot do this. I *think* I remember a talk where it was on the list of things they're going to do. I am certain there's no "getter" API equivalent to the "setter" API which is `Node.setStyle("fx-..." )` etc etc. Of course there's nothing like `getWidth()` or `getHeight()` for CSS either. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. Perhaps I am wrong and we'll both learn something ;)